# How and where to display custom 404 page not found jsp page in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, custom-error-pages

I want to display 404 custom error page when a user try to hit unknown resource instead of whitelabel error.
Example : https://www.example.com/blog  (this is valid request, as blog page is there)
but if user hits https://www.example.com/blog/unknown-parameter (this is not a valid request)
then, will display custom page not found or 404 page.
So I am new to spring boot and I have no idea how to do it.
I have created a custom error page inside src/main/webapp/views/page-not-found.jsp.

If any one can help, will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom error controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(“/error”)
public class Error Controller {

    @GetMapping
    String getErrorPage() {
       // your code here…
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not worked for me